# How to auto-scale a scene in different resolution?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, scenekit

I overlayed Spritekit background and labels on the Scenekit scene.
When I try to run the program on the iPhone 5 and iPhone 6 simulator, the SpriteKit nodes don't auto fit the different devices.
How to fix this?

```
class GameOverlay: SKScene {

    override init(size: CGSize) {
        super.init(size: size)

        //Start Game
        let gameStart = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "GameStart")
        gameStart.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x:0.5,y:0.5)
        gameStart.position = CGPointMake(-size.width / 2 + 400 , size.height / 2 - 200)
        gameStart.size = CGSize(width: 356 / 2, height: 86 / 2)
        gameStart.setScale(1.0)
        gameStart.zPosition = 1
        SKSceneScaleMode.ResizeFill
        self.addChild(gameStart)


        //Quit node
        let quit = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "AvenirNext-Bold")
        self.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)
        self.scaleMode = .AspectFill
        quit.text =  "Quit"
        quit.fontColor = UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 255.0/255.0, blue: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        quit.position = CGPointMake(-size.width / 2 + 580 , size.height / 2 - 360)
        quit.name = "quit"
        self.addChild(quit)

        //BG
        let bg = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "22")
        bg.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x:0.5,y:0.5)
        bg.position = CGPoint(x:0.0, y:0.0)
        bg.zPosition = -1
        SKSceneScaleMode.ResizeFill
        self.addChild(bg)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Step 1

Writing

```
SKSceneScaleMode.ResizeFill
```

does produce no effect.

To resize you scene you must write

```
self.scaleMode = .ResizeFill
```

### Step 2

This code

```
self.scaleMode = .ResizeFill
```

does not scale you scene, it simply resize it.

To scale your scene (and automatically its content) you can write

```
self.scaleMode = .Fill
```

Comment: @CuiLongchang: Good, please accept my answer if it does solve your problem.